# Alias for Devise URL Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails,I am using Devise gem for authentication on table account_user.
When I do `rake routes` I get

```
new_account_user_session GET /account_users/sign_in(.:format)account_user/sessions#new
```

So my login page is `xyz.com/account_users/sign_in`.
I want to change the sign-in page to just `xyz.com`

I don't have any routes for the same in my routes.rb file, I thought devise is automatically generating routes for this.

Is there a way I can add alias/override for this devise generated routes, or redirect user to `xyz.com` instead of `xyz.com/account_users/sign_in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set root to devise sign_in, so in your route file there should be

```
devise_for :account_users
devise_scope :account_user do
  root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

this will set your root path to sign_in

or if you want to rename the route to 'login'

```
devise_for :account_users
devise_scope :account_user do
  get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

more here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes